# angular behavioral subjects and subscribing in component

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, angular6

I have two independent dropdowns in the navbar. Let´s say one for class and another for teachers. Now, in my student component, I want to subscribe both these drop-down values, i.e. when either of the dropdown value is changed, the student component should reload and show the behavior according to the selection.

In my component I am doing:

```
export class Student{
    sub1: Subscription;
    sub2: Subscription;
    constructor(navbar: NavbarService){
        this.sub1 = this.navbar.teacher$.subscribe(
            method1();
        )
        this.sub2= this.navbar.class$.subscribe(
            method1();
        )
    }

    method1(){//implementation}
}
```

Is this the right approach? Can I use one reference, i.e. only sub1 to listen to both the observable changes? If you can explain by example that will be really appreciated.

Comment: try this: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use RXJS:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

export class YourClass{

   ... 

   public yourMethod()
   {
       combineLatest(teachers$, class$).subscribe((result) => {

          // do your stuff
       });
   }

}
```

You can find more details here:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: Thanks Exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to create a new Shared service like `shared.service.ts` to share data between both components and then import `BehaviorSubject` in your `shared.service.ts`

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
```

create a new Behaviour Subject variable to change values and another your components can subscribe to in your shared service.

```
value = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
_value = this.value.asObservable();
```

also add a function to add the next value

```
nextValue(data) {
  this.value.next(data);
}
```

in your Teacher and Student component import your shared service and create a variable to hold the data

```
import { SharedService } from '../services/shared.service'; // where you put your 
                                                            //services

sub1; // hold your data here

constructor(private shared: SharedService) {
  shared._value.subscribe(r => this.sub1 = r); // subscribe here
}
```

and then if you'd like to change the value just use

```
method( newValue ) {
  this.shared.nextValue(newValue);
}
```

and it should update in both your teacher and student component